# React Router Wrap Multiple Routes in a Redirect

Tags: reactjs, react-router, router

Given an authentication token and a function `checkToken` how would I go about rerouting from multiple routes using the react router to prevent repetition like the below?

```
<Route exact path="/" render={() => {
  return checkToken() ? (<Dashboard />) : (<Redirect to="/login" />)
}} />
<Route exact path="/about" render={() => {
  return checkToken() ? (<About />) : (<Redirect to="/login" />)
}} />
```

It gets cumbersome if I have a couple dozen routes to have this repeated.

Surely there must be a better way!

Comment: Are you familiar with the Higher Order Component (HOC) pattern?

Answer (score 4):

Here is how I like to handle this:

1. Create a `routers` folder in `src`
2. Inside the router folder create 3 files `AppRouter.js`, `PrivateRoute.js` & `PublicRoute.js`

Here is your `PublicRoute.js`:

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

export const PublicRoute = ({ isAuthenticated, component: Component, ...rest }) => (
    <Route {...rest} component={(props) => (
      isAuthenticated ? <Redirect to="/dashboard" /> : <Component {...props} /> 
    )} />
  );

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  isAuthenticated: // however you need to keep track of that...
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(PublicRoute);
```

Here is your `PrivateRoute.js`:

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

export const PrivateRoute = ({ isAuthenticated, component: Component, ...rest }) => (
    <Route {...rest} component={(props) => (
      isAuthenticated ? <Component {...props} /> : <Redirect to="/" />
    )} />
  );

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  isAuthenticated: // however you need to keep track of that...
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(PrivateRoute);
```

And finally here is your `AppRouter.js`:

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

import Dashboard from '../components/Dashboard';
import NotFound from '../components/NotFound';
import Login from '../components/Login';
import PrivateRoute from './PrivateRoute';
import PublicRoute from './PublicRoute';



const AppRouter = () => (
  <BrowserRouter>
      <Switch>
        {/* use PublicRoute for public routes */}
        <PublicRoute exact path="/" component={Login} />
        {/* use PrivateRoute for private routes */}
        <PrivateRoute path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
        <Route component={NotFound} />
      </Switch>
  </BrowserRouter>
);

export default AppRouter;
```

For more info on HOCs (Higher Order Components) look up the docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html

Comment: This seems reasonable, but doesn't it add a lot of boilerplate rather than reduce it?

Comment: @calben I suppose it depends on your app and use case... The idea here is to create those two HOCs and then in your actual `AppRouter` simply use either `PublicRoute` or `PrivateRoute` HOC instead of the `Route` (that we get from the lib)...  Of course, if all you have are just 2 components (DashBoard and Login) it's a bit of an overkill...

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve it is by placing your checkToken function inside componentDidMount so you will always check if your user is authenticated each time this component is mounted.

After that you can do something like this:

```
let routes = (
  <Switch>
    <Route path="/login" component={LoginComponent} />
    <Redirect to="/" />
  </Switch>
);
if (isAuth) {
  routes = (
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/yourRoute" component={YourComponent} />
      <Redirect to="/" />
    </Switch>
  );
}

return (
  <div>
    {routes}
  </div>
```